# Solve return value issue for NodeJS (Express) and Eslint?

Tags: node.js, api, express, eslint

```
module.exports = function protectedRoute(request, response, next) {
  const token = request.headers.authorization;
  if (!token) {
    return response.status(401).json({ message: 'invalid or token missing' });
  }

  const accessToken = token.split(' ')[1];

  jwt.verify(accessToken, 'access', (error, user) => {
    if (error) {
      response.status(401).json({ message: 'User not authenticated' });
    } else {
      request.user = user;
      next();
    }
  });
};
```

Eslint is giving an error: "Expected to return value at the end of function". Now I solved this using:

```
return null; // at the end of the function
```

But I want to return something meaningful like:

```
return response.status(503).json({ message: 'service unavailable' });
```

But this return gives error on API call: "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of a [middleware function](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) like this never examined, therefore it need not return anything. To satisfy eslint, `return null;` is fine.

The problem with your "meaningful" return statement is that it *synchronously* sends a response to the client independent of the outcome of the `jwt.verify` statement. This outcome is handled *asychronously*, in the `(error, user) => ...` callback function. So what happens is: First the 503 response is sent with the "service unavailable" message, and then

- either a 401 response is sent with "user not authenticated" (if the callback has an `error`)
- or the next middleware is invoked and will try to send a response.

In both cases, the headers of the second response are set after the first response has already been sent, hence the error. Sending two responses does not make sense, of course.